# How to make SLURM use gres.conf

Tags: slurm

I distribute jobs using SLURM, and I have a generic resource called "cards". In slurm.conf there is a line:

```
GresTypes=cards
```

I do not include this resource in the node configuration lines. Instead, I try and configure it in gres.conf:

```
NodeName=mynode-01 Name=cards Count=2
```

Unfortunately, `scontrol show node mynode-01` shows `Gres=(null)`.

Both slurm.conf and gres.conf are accessible to all the nodes. I tried to run `scontrol reconfigure` and to restart SLURM daemon - it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not include this resource in the node configuration lines.

Gres must be defined both in `slurm.conf` (in the node definition lines) and `gres.conf` to work properly.

The Slurm controller relies on the information in `slurm.conf` while the Slurm daemon on the compute nodes reads the information in `gres.conf`. The info should match.

Comment: But if in slurm.conf I define e.g.: "NodeName=mynode-01 CoresPerSocket=2 Gres=cards:2"  -- then what is the role of gres.conf?  I thought I could notify SLURM about changes in `cards` availability solely by changing gres.conf (which is much convenient to edit programmatically than slurm.conf).

Comment: The `gres.conf` can contain more information about the type of gres and the associated device files for instance. Initially, there was one `gres.conf` file per compute node and only later on did Slurm allow merging them all into one single file.